# Checking if a Chekbox is checked or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

HTML Code:

```
<div class="checkbox" style=" float:left "></div>
<input type="checkbox" class="realcheckbox" id="financing"  />
```

jQuery Code:

```
$(".checkbox").click(function() { 
    var xchecked = $(this).siblings(".realcheckbox").attr("checked");
    if (xchecked == false) {
        $(this).css("background-image","url('checkboxselected.png')");
        $(this).next(".realcheckbox").attr("checked",true);
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background-image","url('checkbox.png')");
        $(this).next(".realcheckbox").attr("checked",false);
    }
});
```

Clicking on the fake checkbox isn't checking the real one, but if the real one is checked, clicking on the fake one is doing the job, means the real one gets unchecked, what's wrong with the first one ?

Comment: This is answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery

Comment: This is answered in the below page mate, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery) Have a nice day!

Comment: Remember that you can check checkboxes in other ways than clicking on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `is(":checked")` to test:

```
var xchecked = $(this).siblings(".realcheckbox").is(":checked");
```

Answer (score 9):

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/ktwDK/3/

good read: http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

`.is(":checked")` will do the trick for you.

**jquery code**

```
$(".realcheckbox").click(function(){
    alert($(this).is(":checked"));
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to check pseudo for that:

```
var xchecked = $(this).siblings(".realcheckbox").is(":checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.checkBox').click(function() {
   var thisCheck = $(this);
 if (thisCheck.is(':checked')) {
//do your stuff
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".checkbox").click(function() { 
    var xchecked = $(this).find(".realcheckbox").prop("checked");
    if (xchecked == false) {
        $(this).css("background-image","url('checkboxselected.png')");
        $(this).next(".realcheckbox").attr("checked",true);
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background-image","url('checkbox.png')");
        $(this).next(".realcheckbox").attr("checked",false);
    }
});
```